# Keep normal bottom margin when there is no top margin

Tags: spacing

I'm using the `geometry` and `fancyhdr` packages to remove the top margin from some pages on my document:

```
\fancypagestyle{special}{
    \newgeometry{top=0mm}
}
```

This works well to remove the top margin on all pages where I use this style, but also changes the apparent bottom margin to be larger, as if removing the top margin offset the entire page upwards. How could I restore the bottom margin back to normal?

**Update:** Here is some compilable code to demonstrate the problem:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{special}{
   \newgeometry{top=0mm}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \restoregeometry
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\thispagestyle{special}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, trim={0 37mm 0 37mm},clip]{Downloads/full.jpg}}

\section*{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Notice the ugly gap at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably add to `textheight` the value or the normal `top`, or specify again `bottom=`. The package will then compute the new text height.

Comment: @Bernard Changing `textheight` or `bottom` do not seem to work.

Comment: I didn't mean changing the bottom, but restating the same value for bottom as before. Other than that, can you please post a small compilable code illustrating your problem?

Comment: @Bernard Question updated with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `newgeometry`, nor `\fancypagestyle`: just load `eso-pic` and the `\AddToShipoutPicture*` command:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

 \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
\makebox[\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[scale = 1.05,valign=t]{SanRomano-all}}}}

\section*{Test}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't this way. The page headers are added *after* the page is already typeset with the current text height. Thus, it might be possible to move the page via `\newgeometry`, but the page is not typeset again.

Therefore, `\newgeometry` should be used outside of a page style, e.g.:

```
\newpage
\newgeometry{...}
...
\newpage
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: See my question update.